# Unsplash Api to download image of a particular size

Tags: javascript, image, performance, api, download

When Unsplash API `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=#{dummy_client_id}` is called it returns JSON in the following format

```
[
  {
    "id": "kmTq5GU6c-0",
    "created_at": "2019-05-27T14:07:14-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-21T01:25:29-04:00",
    "promoted_at": null,
    "width": 5472,
    "height": 3648,
    "color": "#FFFFFF",
    "description": null,
    "alt_description": "man riding black motorcycle",
    "urls": {
      "raw": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-da1f85d3b540?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzMDkxNX0",
      "full": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-da1f85d3b540?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzMDkxNX0",
      "regular": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-da1f85d3b540?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzMDkxNX0",
      "small": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-da1f85d3b540?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzMDkxNX0",
      "thumb": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980394-da1f85d3b540?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=200&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEzMDkxNX0"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/kmTq5GU6c-0",
      "html": "https://unsplash.com/photos/kmTq5GU6c-0",
      "download": "https://unsplash.com/photos/kmTq5GU6c-0/download",
      "download_location": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/kmTq5GU6c-0/download"
    },
    "categories": [
      
    ],
    "likes": 409,
    "liked_by_user": false,
    "current_user_collections": [
      
    ],
    "sponsorship": {
      
    },
    "user": {
      
    }
  }
]
```

I need to download the image and unsplash guidelines states that you need to use `links['download']` to download the image. The downloaded image is always of size greater than 4MB.

How can I download the image of smaller size/ width/ height. ?

Comment: why do you want to download it? If you are using it in web than use urls.raw or any one of them based on ur requirement

Comment: you can also change the query params `w` stand for width and download like a normal file